# Flip an instance

Tags: actionscript-3, width, flash-cs4

I've searched everywhere and never found what I was looking for, simple as it is. I just want to flip an instance vertically and horizontally in ActionScript. I've tried multiplying the width by -1, but it didn't do anything at all. I've looked into transformations but to no avail either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the object's scaleX/scaleY property to -1

Comment: Just note that this will work fine on unscaled items. In my answer I multiply by negative one because this will flip an object regardless of it's scale, maintaining the scale. If you took a scaled object and just set the scaleX or scaleY to -1, you will skew your display object.

Answer (score 3):

sydd is almost right, I think they just typed it wrong in haste. You want to multiply the objects scaleX/scaleY by -1. This inverts the number. For example:

```
myMovie.scaleX *= -1;
```

Will flip horizontally. Likewise:

```
myMovie.scaleY *= -1;
```

Will flip veritcally.